# Hex to bytearray

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, arrays

```
 Dim data As String = "c80378b8"

 Dim bytes As Byte() = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(Me.data.Substring, ".{2}").Select(Function(x) x.Value).ToArray()
```

**Error 1**

```
Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Substring' accepts this number of arguments
```

I want to read the hex string in the `data` variable (2 characters at a time) and then that value (decimal) to be stored as binary format (bytes) in the `bytes`. But it produces above error, what is wrong with this  and what is the correct method? is there any one liner alternative to this?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Imports System.Globalization

Sub Main()
    Dim data As String = "c80378b8"
    Dim bytes As Byte() = BitConverter.GetBytes(Long.Parse(data, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier))
End Sub
```

This code first parses the hex string to a Long and then gets the bytes for it.  The parse will fail if the string is not a hex string.  You may wish to put this code in a method so you can account for that possiblility.

**EDIT:**

If you need to convert strings longer than a Long variable will hold, you can use the `BigInteger` class.  Add a reference to System.Numerics

```
Imports System.Numerics
Imports System.Globalization

Sub Main()
    Dim data As String = "4845484848484848484848484848484848484848484848484848484848484848"
    Dim bigI As BigInteger = BigInteger.Parse(data, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)
    Dim bytes As Byte() = bigI.ToByteArray()
End Sub
```

Comment: `@Chris` no, your code doesn't work with longer string such as `"4845484848484848484848484848484848484848484848484848484848484848"`

Comment: @Pretty_Girl5 - Your question did not say that you had strings that size.  I could only answer the question based on the information you provided.